# Getting list of types that are effected by an extension method in cqlinq

Tags: ndepend

How to get the list of types that are extended by a extension method in ndepend cqlinq? Using reflection to code this seems a bit of donkey work where ndepend is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NDepend code model doesn't have a straight way to resolve the method parameter type. So we can come up with a satisfying answer with code query relying on string formatting extended type name, extracted from the method name. But this query is overly complex and there are edge cases where it won't work properly (explained below).

Here is the code query, it runs fast even on large code base thanks to the use of a dictionary:

```
//
// First let build dicoExtensionMethods 
let dicoExtensionMethods =
(from m in Application.Methods
where m.IsExtensionMethod

// extract extended type simple name (with generic parameters like "IEnumerable<String>")
let beginIndex = m.Name.IndexOf("(") + 1
let endIndex = m.Name.IndexOf(',', beginIndex) > 0 ? m.Name.IndexOf(',', beginIndex) : m.Name.IndexOf(")", beginIndex) 
let extendedTypeSimpleName1 = m.Name.Substring(beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex)

// Take care of generic type first char, like "IEnumerable<"
let extendedTypeSimpleName2 = extendedTypeSimpleName1.IndexOf('<') == -1 ? extendedTypeSimpleName1 :
                              extendedTypeSimpleName1.Substring(0, extendedTypeSimpleName1.IndexOf('<') + 1 )
select new { m, extendedTypeSimpleName2 })
.ToLookup(pair => pair.extendedTypeSimpleName2)
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g=> g.Select(p =>p.m))

//
// Second for each type get extension methods from dicoExtensionMethods 
from t in Types
// Format type name like  "IEnumerable<"
let typeName = !t.IsGeneric ? t.SimpleName : t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.IndexOf('<') + 1 )
where dicoExtensionMethods.ContainsKey(typeName) 
let methods = dicoExtensionMethods[typeName]
select new { t, methods }
```

As written it is a complex query because of type name formatting, and it works fine most of the time.

[image: NDepend Code Query Result Extension Methods]

However when it comes to extending generic types, it says for example that `IEnumerable<T>` is extended by both methods that extend `IEnumerable<String>` and `IEnumerable<Int32>`. This is acceptable, but it is not 100% correct.

[image: NDepend Code Query Result Extension Methods]

Also if you extend several types with same name but various generic arity (like `Func<T1,T2>` and `Func<T1,T2,T3>`), then this code query won't work properly.

The same if you extend several types with same name, declared in different assemblies or namespace (which is a code smell anyway).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Holy hell! What an awesome answer thank you, one more reason to buy NDepend, thank you

Comment: You are welcome! I am still a bit frustrated by the shortcoming explained, but in the future this will be fixed! At least we come up with an answer correct for 99% real world cases :)

Comment: I don't mean to be imposing, can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481538/how-to-get-list-of-extension-methods-in-a-solution-or-project-in-vs2013 , it is I believe simpler version of this question and I be very happy by just finding the extension methods on a solution.

Comment: Done! I prefer the current solution :)