# How to get list of extension methods in a solution or project in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, ndepend, cqlinq

How does one get the list of extension methods in a solution/project?

Is there anything in VS 2013 by default to achieve that like class view or using ndepend cqlinq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write the code query:

```
from m in Application.Methods
where m.IsExtensionMethod
select m
```

For a code query that group extension method sby types extended see:
[Getting list of types that are effected by an extension method in cqlinq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29472845/27194)