# CQLINQ for list of methods that take a type as a parameter?

Tags: ndepend, cqlinq

What is the CQLINQ to get list of all the methods taking a (compatible) type or interface at least as one their parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [Getting list of types that are effected by an extension method in cqlinq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29472845/27194)

an actual limitation of NDepend is that you cannot access method parameter types.

Hence you can still obtain result by dealing with `IMethod.Name` string matching (since parameter types are listed in, like `"Method(Int32,List<T>)"`) and get inspiration from [CQLINQ for list of methods returning a specific type or interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29505525/27194)